# Total Count of each column

Tags: sql

I have two columns:

```
Segments           consumers
Premium            15630
Low                5000
Premium             5
Family shopper     45600
Family Shopper       56
```

and I want to have a total result for each segment like:

```
Segments                   Consumers
Premium                     xxx
Low                         xxx
Family Shopper              xxx
```

Comment: Can't really follow what your table looks like but likely what you need is the aggregate function `SUM(column_which_you_want_the_total_of)` and the `group by` clause.

Comment: I'm having trouble to understand your question, could you edit and try to be more specific about the data you had and the expected output? also specify the dbms that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select segments, SUM(consumers)
from your_table_name
group by segments;
```

This will be the same for pretty much all database systems but you might wanna read the documentation on those clauses for your database system as they are quite fundamental.
See [PostgreSQL SUM](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sum-function/).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Segments, SUM(Consumers) FROM Table GROUP BY Segments
```